# impresspages color picker incorrect color code

Tags: jquery, color-picker, impresspages

I have been struggling to get default color picker work. When I add a new color field ( new \Ip\Form\Field\Color) on form page then after selecting color from drop down I get error "incorrect color code". And when I checked value returned is something like this "hsv(0, 25%, 34%)".

After checking in Core files, Color Form field file then I found following function which is validating it.

```
public function validate($values, $valueKey, $environment)
{
    if (preg_match('/^#([a-f]|[A-F]|[0-9]){3}(([a-f]|[A-F]|[0-9]){3})?$\b/', $values[$valueKey])) {
        return parent::validate($values, $valueKey, $environment);
    } else {
        if ($environment == \Ip\Form::ENVIRONMENT_ADMIN) {
            return __('Incorrect color code', 'Ip-admin', false);
        } else {
            return __('Incorrect color code', 'Ip', false);
        }
    }
}
```

Can you please check and let me know why it is generating HSV code for color "hsv(0, 25%, 34%)"

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And here is a complete fix :

https://github.com/impresspages/ImpressPages/commit/bb8a07c2a575479c8a4f47a61b72415e16b8510b

https://github.com/impresspages/ImpressPages/commit/ad877a5173b2d7b118e17849fed9d2ae9abc827e

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in current value of that field. If JavaScript can't understand the value, it falls back to HSV. Set the default (or current) value to RGB. Eg. #ffffff. That will solve the problem for now. I will try to do something to fix this in general.

Comment: Thanks for your response! How and where I can set default value?

Comment: It depends where and how are you using it. Is it GRID? If this is grid, have a look at the existing values in the database if there are any incorrect values. Also you can set 'defaultValue' setting for the color field in GRID

If this is standard form, add 'value' property with default value.